# Blender shape keys in godot greyed out

Tags: blender, godot

I have a couple models with shape keys from Blender. When I export it as obj and import it in Godot, the shape key area is greyed out like below. What is the cause of this? In some tutorials on Youtube (ex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJClHuIXRUM) the box for blend shapes is different and has their sliders in it.

[image: Greyed out]

Answer (score 0):

Came back later when I realized this was never answered

You have to enable fbx in the Project Settings and then use fbx or alternatively enable blender and take stuff directly from your .blend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Blender you have to export in .gltf format and check the following export options.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDr7p.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).